# How to remove interior edges from objects in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let's say I have an array of objects `objects` and each object contains `vertices`

So for example, let's say I have 2 `objects`, each containing 4 `vertices`, and I plot the vertices and connect them using a line in Matlab:

```
size_vertices=size(vertices);

for o=1:length(objects)
    for v=1:size_vertices(1)-1
        plot([vertices(o, v,1) vertices(o, v+1,1)], [vertices(o,v,2) vertices(o,v+1,2)], '-k' )
    end
end
```

So let's say `vertices(1,:,:)=[1 5; 1 1; 5 1; 4 6]`

and `vertices(2,:,:)=[5 10; 3 8; 1 5; 4 6]`

Now, let's say I have an arbitrary number of objects (for example, in order from 1-6 in the diagram below), and each object could contain an arbitrary number of vertices (not just 4 like in the example above). (The ellipses are not part of the edges, they are just there to indicate where the vertices are)

Is there a way to remove the inner edges using Matlab?

Comment: It seems you want to find duplicate edges and remove them. Find edges that have the same two vertices?

Comment: No, I just want to remove edges that aren't on the boundary of the object, which is why I want to remove the red edges in the diagram that is above the bottom-most diagram

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As Cris noticed in comment, what we need is calculate the appearance of each edges, and only plot those appeared for only once. Function `tabulate` enables us to achieve that:

```
% Test Data
clc; clear;
vertices{1}=[1 5; 1 1; 5 1; 4 6];
vertices{2}=[5 10; 3 8; 1 5; 4 6];

% To ensure every objects are closed
for ii=1:length(vertices)
  vertices{ii}=[vertices{ii}; vertices{ii}(1,:)];  
end

% Save Egdes
edges{1}=num2str([0 0 0 0]);
for o=1:length(vertices)
    for v=1:size(vertices{o},1)-1
        tmp1=[vertices{o}(v,1) vertices{o}(v+1,1)];
        tmp2=[vertices{o}(v,2) vertices{o}(v+1,2)];
        if tmp1(1) == tmp1(2)
            tmp2=sort(tmp2);
        end
        [~,indi]=sort(tmp1);
        edges{end+1}=num2str([tmp1(indi) tmp2(indi)]);
    end
end

% Calcualte the number of appearence of each edges
sta=tabulate(edges);
figure(1); hold on
for ii=2:size(sta,1)
  if sta{ii,2} > 1
      continue
  end
  tmp=str2num(sta{ii,1});
  plot(tmp(1:2),tmp(3:4), '-k' )
end
axis([0 6 0 11])
```

Note that I changed `vertices` into a CellArray, as there is a triangle, not only quadrangles in your final result.